# \pageref out of sync with \label

Tags: cross-referencing, page-numbering, labels

I have `\pagerfer` pointing to the code listing on the next page. The listing is equipped with `\label`. When I generate PDF from the TeX file using

```
latexmk -pdflatex='pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode' -pdf -bibtex -f %f
```

command, the reference shows correct page number, but when clicked jumps to the wrong page. My initial problem was that the code listing didn't fit on the remaining space of the page, and so I added `\newpage` before it. This fixed the number in the `\pageref`, but not the behavior.

Below are the "interesting" bits, which I think are relevant to the problem:

```
\subsection{Larger example}
\label{sec-2-3}

[...]

Whoa, this was a lot of code (see page \pageref{if_pressed}) [...]

\newpage

\begin{minted}[bgcolor=codebg,fontsize=\scriptsize]{prolog}
if_pressed(Button, modifiers(Playback, Position, Content, Mode), NextState):-
    ( ... ).
\end{minted}
\label{if_pressed}
\subsection{Queries}
```

Comment: Have you tried inserting the instruction `\phantomsection` between `\newpage` and `\begin{minted}`?

Comment: When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should like like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves a lot of time for everyone.

Comment: It might help to look at the aux file and see what the line for if_pressed contains.

Comment: Sorry, took me a while to come back to this. Nope, I didn't try the `\phantomsection`, but that did help! Didn't know about such thing. Please, @Mico, feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you insert the instruction

```
\phantomsection
```

between `\newpage` and `\begin{minted}`. The purpose of this instruction is to provide an "anchor" of sorts for hyperref, so that a cross-reference to an object that doesn't have an automatic counter associated with it will still take you to the intended location within the document.

Comment: Having the same problem, I tried inserting '\phantomsection' right before '\label' and it worked. So I thought of redefining '\label' but... is there a reason that \label does not automatically insert itself a '\phantomsection'?

Comment: @A.G. - The macro `\label` has been around far longer than the `hyperref` package, and it has to work regardless of whether `hyperref` is loaded or not. If `\label` is associated with an entity -- e.g. `\section` and `\caption` -- or environment -- e.g., `equation`, `theorem`, etc -- that increments an associated encounter, the instruction `\phantomsection` is redundant. The only time you really need `\phantomsection` is if you want to create a hyperlink to an unnumbered `\section`ing header or to an environment (say, a `minted` environment) that's not numbered.